# What does this generating function terminology mean?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am reading Zeilberger's [paper](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/feller.html) on repeated coin tossing (winning or losing a dollar each time), and I came upon the following:

> If you factor a break-even
>   sequence (i.e. with sum $0$) according to its sign-changes,
>   and look at it as a sequence of $P$'s and $N$'s,
>   we have the following *regular expression*
>   $$
> empty \vee P(NP)^{*} \vee P(NP)^{*}N \vee N(PN)^{*} \vee N(PN)^{*}P \quad,
> $$

where we call

> a segment between two consecutive break-even times, where it was   *not losing* in-between, a $P$-segment

and

> a segment between two
>   consecutive break-even times, where it was *it not winning*
>   in-between, an $N$-segment.

I think Zeilberger is saying that any sequence of wins and losses is either empty, or a concatenation of a $P$-segment with an $(NP)^*$ segment, and so on.  My question is, what does $*$ mean?  I'm guessing it means repetition: $(X)^*=\emptyset\vee X \vee XX \vee XXX \vee \cdots$.  Is this the right interpretation?

Comment: Yes: it’s the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) operation.